# Unity Hub 2.4.2 does not open a login window

Tags: unity, macos

I just installed Unity Hub 2.4.2 on my MacBook Pro 2015 running macOS Big Sur. However, when attempting to open a login window from the hub, it opens briefly and then quits. (The hub remains open, but the login window closes.)

I've already tried:

- Quitting and reopening the hub
- Uninstalling and reinstalling the hub

Are there any suggestions on how to fix this? Does anybody have the same problem?